# Is there a word for "re-parent"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parent) for "parent" includes:

> an ancestor, precursor, or progenitor.
>
> a source, origin, or cause.

Is there a term that describes changing the parent of a child object to a different source, origin or cause? My first thought was "re-parent" or "reparent" but neither seem to be well accepted terms.

Comment: In what context are you doing this? Probably not a natural biological/adoptive parent; is it a computer programming issue?

Comment: There are few contexts in which changing the parent of something (in either of the above senses) is even possible, from an ontological standpoint, which would seem to mitigate strongly against such a word arising organically--although there may be jargon for specialized applications of the concept.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about domain-specific terminology. To the extent that such an action could be meaningful outside the "inheritance-based" software context, the standard English "verb" would probably have to be ***reassign parentage***.

Comment: The definitions you've cited are nouns, but the word you're asking for is a verb. Presumably if one allows verbing "parent" then one should allow reparent?

Comment: Why not [adopt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/adopt)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It isn't about domain specific terminology. Lots of various things operate under the parent-child association. It's a general term.

Comment: @MrHen: Perhaps there are other "domain specific" contexts that also use ***reparent***, but I think it would be ridiculous to claim it's therefore a normal English word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I wasn't trying to claim it *was* a normal word. I actually note the exact opposite in my question.

Comment: Well, since you asked the question, I'm obviously on a hiding to nothing attempting to convince you the "reassignment" sense is so far removed from what we normally understand by the word "parent" that there can't really be *any* "normal" word for what you seek.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sorry, I'm not understanding your sentence. Can you restate that?

Comment: The fact that you've asked this question implies you don't think it's Off Topic (because domain-specific). I think it is, because outside of highly-specialised contexts such as OOPS programming, it simply doesn't make sense to change the parent of an offspring to a different parent, so there won't be a word for the process. In the circumstances, we're obviously coming at this one from opposite directions, so I have no hope of convincing you to adopt my position (i.e. - that this isn't about "normal" use of English such as would be relevant to ELU).

Comment: I think I disagree that this is "off-topic because it's domain-specific". It's a question about an understandable word in English to convey a specific idea. Since [*parent* is a verb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parent?q=parent) and *re-* is productive, there does exist a contender. It might not be used about people; I could imagine it used about **animals** though. However, if the community believes it to be off-topic, then you know what to do...!

Comment: @Andrew: So far as I know, in "normal" English, the verb *to parent* only ever means *to act as a parent [to "offspring"]*. I can *almost* imaging a "serial foster-parent" who wants to "retire" saying *"Don't assign me another foster-child. I don't want to re-parent"*. But in the "weirdness" stakes at the conceptual level, that's right up there with ***re-die*** for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Okay, so what is the appropriate "normal" English word for "changing one's parent"?

Comment: @MrHen: Erm... like I said, in *my* "real-world", the concept itself doesn't really make sense, so I wouldn't expect there to be a word for it. And I don't really see what context you have in mind when you talk of "changing one's parent", but it doesn't seem very close to the one in the original question, which seems to be more a matter of a *programmer* making the relevant adjustments so the "parent" of a software object can be altered. Which might be better called *reassigning higher-level inheritance paths* (software mod), rather than *reassigning parentage* (administrative adjustment).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think "there is no such word because this concept doesn't exist" is technically an answer... so, okay. I find it strange that you seem to have pigeonholed yourself into thinking of this as a programming question.

Comment: It seems natural enough to me. You referred to *child **object*** in the question text, and the only answer after several hours clearly refers to the OOPS context. Perhaps you should have been reconsidering how you've phrased the question, rather than arguing with me about the closevote. I mean - I have to assume you have *some* context in mind, in order to ask the question at all. If it's *not* the OOPS one, why can't you explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't feel that I need to. The context is the definition of the word parent; the question is what you call changing that parent. I used the example "re-parent" because I encounter it in my day to day job and then note that this seems to be abnormal (as in, too domain specific; as in, agreeing with you). Thus, the question is whether there is an appropriate English term for the concept. Your objection appears to be "there is a domain specific context for that concept; therefore this is off-topic."

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused here. My understanding is there's a general consensus that we expect *all* ELU questions to provide as much context as possible, and I'd have thought this particularly applies to SWR's. It's not the fact that there *is* an existing domain-specific word here *(reparent)* that makes it OT - it's that for most purposes the *concept* of such a word can only exist in specialised domains. By the same token, perhaps the cheese-making industry uses **remature** or an equivalent word, but I'd say it was OT to ask for a different term there (there's no meaningful referent).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I've provided enough context to explain the meaning of the word I'm looking for. I don't understand the confusion.

Comment: Your only "context" seems to be *changing the parent of a child **object***, but you seem to be denying that you're looking for a "domain-specific" answer (and you haven't accepted Nate's take on the matter). In that domain-specific context, you really *can* change the actual "parent" of an object, but I can't easily imagine any other context where this is possible. All other contexts that make sense to me net down to ***correcting*** a (previously erroneous) *classification*, which isn't really the same thing at all.

Comment: Please consider [chat] as an alternative to extended discussion in comments.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My context is the definition of the word "parent", which is quoted in the question. The use of "object" is just me talking like a programmer because I happen to be one. You are overemphasizing its usage. I know this because I know what I meant and why I used the word. I haven't accepted Nate's answer because I always wait a few days before accepting answers. Your lack of imagination isn't my problem and it doesn't automatically make this question off-topic, which was my point in earlier comments. I have no idea why you are objecting so strongly to this question. :/

Comment: @Matt Эллен: Do you not think it's better this interaction should be more clearly visible while the question is receiving so little attention and *doesn't have an accepted answer?* Although I personally haven't voted here (I'm still trying to understand the question better), we can assume MrHen has asked in good faith, and it deserves more than just a solitary downvote to the question, plus two upvotes for the answer *he already said he didn't want*. You're in the driving seat, but do I not have a point?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Matt's just posting the boilerplate for long comment threads. FWIW, I don't have a problem with an answer in the form, "No, there is no such word outside of a domain specific context. The closest would be something like X..." I don't know if such a term exists *otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question.*

Comment: @ MrHen: Fair enough. Someone else can pick the bones out of my comments and post it. I will give further consideration to why I think *"generic terms for things which only have meaning in special domains"* is Off Topic (would it make any difference if there *were* an answer?). But not here, not now! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Nate points out, *reparent* has a "domain-specific" sense sufficiently well established as to merit an SO tag. And OED has these entries first recorded in the 70s...

> **reparenting** Psychol. (orig. and chiefly U.S.).
>     noun: *Any of various therapeutic techniques intended to treat emotional and psychological problems relating to the parenting a person experienced as a child.*
>
> **reparent** Psychol. (orig. and chiefly U.S.).
>     verb trans.: *To treat by the process of reparenting. Cf. **reparenting** n.*

...which is obviously a *totally different* domain-specific sense (there may be others, I don't know).

The point being that the most morphologically natural way to convey ***verb again*** is ***re[-]verb***. Therefore ***reparent*** has to be the front-runner for a "generic" verb in OP's context. The fact that it has domain-specific senses (unknown to most native speakers) doesn't affect its suitability for more general use.

The reason it's not really an "accepted" term is just that it doesn't reference a concept that's easily understood and *useful* in more general contexts. I can't find any written instances of *reparent* more than half a century old that aren't presaging the physchology usage. It just doesn't mean enough.

Answer (score 3):

*Reparent* is the standard term in computer programming and related contexts.  For instance, [StackOverflow has a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reparenting).